# is_lock_free not defined in std::atomic<T> in gcc 4.7.2?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, atomic

I encounter this compiler error

```
function std::atomic::is_lock_free() const: error: undefined reference 
to '__atomic_is_lock_free'
```

when compiling code like below using gcc 4.7.2 on linux.

```
struct S {
  int a;
  int b;
};


  std::atomic<S> s;
  cout << s.is_lock_free() << endl;
```

Comment: Unlikely to make you happy, but: It seems to work on gcc 4.8 and ICC 13.

Comment: @us2012 is `std::atomic<S>` on user-defined POD types standard or a GCC extension? [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) only says that "full specializations" define atomic types and that "the following full specializations are provided"

Comment: @Stephen - There is a generic `atomic<T>` in the standard (requiring T to be trivially copyable). Its `is_lock_free()` should likely return `false` and not use the compiler intrinsic.

Comment: @BoPersson ok, I think someone needs to update cppreference then, it doesn't mention anything about that or the requirement of `T` being trivially copyable

Comment: @BoPersson - if the type `T` is small enough to be handled with hardware atomic instructions (typically no larger than the largest integral type) `atomic<T>` can be lock free.

Comment: I ran into this exact situation on an embedded ARM linux codebase using gcc 4.7.3. As a workaround, I'm currently wrapping a struct like yours in a union with a 64 bit int to enforce the behavior I want, and it turns out that is_lock_free() is provided for workaround.

Comment: The result looks something similar to: union Foo { long long int s; struct S { int a; int b;}};

Answer (score 11):

[Atomic API isn't complete in GCC 4.7:](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM)

> - When lock free instructions are not available (either through hardware or OS support) atomic operations are left as function calls to be resolved by a library. **Due to time constraints and an API which is not finalized, there is no libatomic supplied with GCC 4.7. This is easily determined by encountering unsatisfied external symbols beginning with `__atomic_*`.**

Since there is no `libatomic` shipped with GCC 4.7 you need to use another compiler which actually supports the features you want or provide the missing features ([sample implementation](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=libatomic.c)).

Comment: Well, the gcc guys provide a sample implementation of libatomic in a single file, in a link just one paragraph below the one you quoted: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=libatomic.c It can be compiled and linked with programs that otherwise fail to compile with gcc4.7. (No idea how efficient or correct this implementation is, though.)