# linker issue with atomic composite struct c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc

I'm failing to compile the following program under the environment Cygwin and using gcc 4.9.3

```
#include <atomic>

struct composite_struct
{
  int anInt;
  int* aPointer;
};

int main()
{
  composite_struct non_atomic_struct;
  non_atomic_struct.anInt = 1001;
  non_atomic_struct.aPointer = new int(1000);

  std::atomic<composite_struct> atomic_struct;
  atomic_struct.store(non_atomic_struct);
  return 0;
}
```

The linker sends error msg `[...]"undefined reference to '__atomic_store_16'"
[...] relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol '__atomic_store_16'[...]`

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311073/stdatomic-library-dependency-gcc-4-7-3/25358842#25358842) that the problem exists on an earlier version of gcc, is it still the case for gcc 4.9.3?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably just need to tell gcc to link against atomic. Example: `g++ -std=c++11 -latomic example.cpp`

Comment: I tried compiling with the -latomic option since it was in the other thread but I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Compiles and runs fine for me, on GCC 4.9.2 (using `-latomic`) on a GNU/Linux system. Try also adding `-mthread`, GCC requires it to generate multithreaded code correctly.

Comment: thanks @DanielKO. It looks like it's not working under Cygwin environment(tried 4.9.2 and 4.9.3). I was able to compile and link as well using visual studio express 2013.
Note that the gcc option `-mthread` is specific to the MinGW environment

Answer (score 0):

There is a portability issue with the code.

The snippet

1. does compile with Visual Studio Express 2013 and on a GNU/Linux system.
2. does not compile(linker fails) under cygwin environment with gcc 4.9.2 or 4.9.3