# C++ 11 undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'

Tags: c++, c++11, stdatomic

The following code fails to link:

```
#include <atomic>                                                                                                                                                             
struct A
{
    unsigned long a;
    unsigned long b;
};                                                                                                                                                           
struct B
{
    void set(A tmp)
    {
        _a.store(tmp);
    }
    std::atomic<A> _a;
 };                                                                                                                                                           

 int main()
{
   B b;
   b.set(A());
   return  0;
}
```

With the following error:

```
/tmp/cc8gyaZM.o: In function `std::atomic<A>::store(A, std::memory_order)':
dryn.cpp:     (.text._ZNSt6atomicI1AE5storeES0_St12memory_order[_ZNSt6atomicI1AE5storeES0_St12memory_order]+0x3e): undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
```

If I replace the unsigned long-s with anything that is up-to int in size, this compiles just fine. Using g++ 4.7.2 . Do you have any idea why is that?

Compiled with command:

```
g++ dryn.cpp --std=c++11
```

Comment: Show your command line, what arch are you compiling for? Did you try `-latomic`?

Comment: I tried it, "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latomic"

Comment: Hmm indeed libatomic seems to be new in 4.8.

Comment: Fwiw, clang  eats this up without issue (Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn))

Comment: On linux clang fails just as much, with undefined __atomic_store (libstdc++) or __sync_lock_test_and_set_16 (libc++). g++ accepts the code with -m32...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15204653/1918193

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25358842/1918193

Comment: I see, and probably not implemented in your linux clang version as well...

Answer (score 7):

As answered by [Zeta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15204653/2972255):

> [Atomic API isn't complete in GCC 4.7:](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM)
>
> > - When lock free instructions are not available (either through hardware or OS support) atomic operations are left as function calls
> >       to be resolved by a library. **Due to time constraints and an API
> >       which is not finalized, there is no libatomic supplied with GCC 4.7.
> >       This is easily determined by encountering unsatisfied external symbols
> >       beginning with `__atomic_*`.**
>
> Since there is no `libatomic` shipped with GCC 4.7 you need to use
>   another compiler which actually supports the features you want or
>   provide the missing features ([sample implementation](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=libatomic.c)).

Comment: comments: Install libatomic to fix it. (note that in GCC the dll named 'libatomic.so.1' , so using -l:libatomic.so.1 to linking)