# Atomic objects of trivially copyable types in GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, atomic, stdatomic

According to the C++ standard, `std::atomic` can be combined with any trivially copyable type. However, GCC produces the following error messages:

```
#include <atomic>
struct TriviallyCopyableType {
  int a, b, c, d;
};
int main() {
  std::atomic<TriviallyCopyableType> a;
  a.store({});      // undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
  a.is_lock_free(); // undefined reference to `__atomic_is_lock_free'
}
```

Clang and Microsoft's compiler do not complain. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known problem? After all, atomic operations were implemented years ago in GCC 4.4. Are there any workarounds other than using a different compiler? Since Clang implements `std::atomic<TriviallyCopyableType>` even lock-free, I do not want to use explicit locking.

Comment: fine on gcc 6.3. I think you need a newer compiler. Yours is ancient.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call 5.4 ancient...

Comment: It seems [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15204653/1120273) is still relevant. Possibly, you need to includue `-latomic`.

Comment: @user1494080 forgive me. You wrote 4.4

Comment: @DietmarKühl That's the solution. GCC is bundled with the correct library, I only had to specify `-latomic`. I wouldn't have thought that I have to explicitly specify libraries in order to compile code using only standard constructs. Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: If you're using that code, you should probably use `-mcx16` on x86-64 to let the compiler use `cmpxchg16b`.  That could enable lock-free 16-byte ops.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984153/implement-aba-counter-with-c11-cas/38991835#38991835.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is compiled from the comments.

You need to explicitly link the atomic operations library with your program by specifying `-latomic` on the command line.

`-mcx16` may enable lock-free atomic operations on 128-bit data types.